# Dropdown menu not showing when using position: absolute;

Tags: html, css

I've just turned my website into a responsive layout and along the way I've somehow managed to make my dropdown menus not work. When hovering over **'Drop-downs'** they don't display unless I'm using position: relative. They worked before using position: absolute - but it seems they only work with position relative now. When using relative it uses the width which messes up the navigation bar.

Using relative: http://d.pr/i/tp5R 
Using absolute: http://d.pr/i/j7r1

**CSS for my sub-menu**

```
div.left_first_header ul.sub-menu {
    width: 125px;
    top: 14px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    background: url(images/drop_down_bg.jpg);
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

**jQuery for the drop down functionality**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery("ul.dropdown li").hover(function() {
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("hover");
        jQuery('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
});
```

**My website**
http://wpvault.com/kahlam/

Considering it's 4am I've probably made a really stupid simple mistake.

I apologise if I've missed anything.

Comment: Looking at your website, I don't see any content in the DOM that would appear when you hover. Is it supposed to be in the markup or added dynamically? Nevermind, I was looking in the wrong place. Looking again.

Comment: Provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use jQuery for this. Try using CSS `:hover`

```
<div class="left_first_header">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        Dropdown
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>item</li>              
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left_first_header .sub-menu {
    width: 125px;
    top: 14px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    background: url(images/drop_down_bg.jpg);
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    display: none;
}


.left_first_header .dropdown:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}​
```

CSS demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TZbfJ/

EDIT: But if you still want to use jquery, try this:

```
.left_first_header .sub-menu {
    width: 125px;
    top: 14px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    display: none;
    background-color: blue;     
    margin-top: 4px;    
}

.dropdown {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").show();        
    }).mouseleave(function(){
       $(this).find(".sub-menu").hide();
    });
})
```

jQuery demo: http://jsfiddle.net/63hkm/

Comment: It's already built around jQuery so I'm a little reluctant to change it when it's just a positioning error.

Comment: @Xiy, see now with position adjust.